# to use self-defined deleter in shared_ptr

Tags: c++, templates, shared-ptr

I define a class, which has a member template, in place of default deleter of std::shared_ptr:

```
class DebugDelete {
    public:
        DebugDelete(std::ostream &s = std::cerr): os(s) { }
        // as with any function template, the type of T is deduced by the compiler
        template <typename T> void operator()(T *p) const
        {
           os << "deleting unique_ptr" << std::endl;
           delete p;
        }
    private:
        std::ostream &os;
};
```

When I apply it to the following code, some errors were reported:

```
class A {
    public:
        // [Error] class 'A' does not have any field named 'r'
        A(std::shared_ptr<std::set<int>> p): r(p) { } // 1: How can I use self-defined deleter to initialize r in constructor
        A(int i): s(new std::set<int>, DebugDelete()) { } // 2: OK, what is the difference between this constructor and 3
    private:
        // [Error] expected identifier before 'new'
        // [Error] expected ',' or '...' before 'new'
        std::shared_ptr<std::set<int>> r(new std::set<int>, DebugDelete()); // 3: error
        std::shared_ptr<std::set<int>> s;
};
```

Comment: I suspect many of the errors you're receiving have *nothing* to do with custom deleting. Of course, including the actual error messages in your question (which should *always* be done)  would confirm that.

Comment: @WhozCraig I've added the error messages in the code.

Comment: You cannot initialize a member in-class with this syntax. Try brace-or-equal initializer.

Comment: @n.m. But in a member function the line I labeled 3 works, just like what I commented Blue moe's answer.

Comment: In a member function is one thing. Not in a member function is another thing. Anyway, just always use braces: `std::shared_ptr<std::set<int>> r{new std::set<int>, DebugDelete()};`

Comment: @n.m. Alright, I remember this brace-method. Here is another question, if `map<string, shared_ptr<set<int>>> m` needs a custom deleter for shared_ptr, how can I initialize it? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In initialize_list you can used self-defined deleter like

```
shared_ptr<set<int>> r = shared_ptr<set<int>>(new set<int>, DebugDelete());
```

and you should not use one shared_ptr to initialize another one.

Comment: I changed my code as you said and it compiled. But I also define a member function of class A - `void B() { shared_ptr<set<int>> ptr(new set<int>, DebugDelete()); }` - both `public` and `private` compile. How did it happen?

Comment: Your function void B() is constructor a shared_ptr named ptr. My answer is assign a member variable.In C++11 standard, member variable can be initialized in-class definition.example:[link](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/data_members)

Comment: n.m.'s answer is another one way to initialized member variable.the Initializer_lists ,see:[link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Initializer_lists)

Comment: Your map `map<string, shared_ptr<set<int>>> m` can used like `shared_ptr<set<int>> ptr = shared_ptr<set<int>>(new set<int> , DebugDelete()); m["onestring"] = ptr; `, or `typedef map<string,shared_ptr<set<int>>>::value_type S_SP; m = {S_SP("string",ptr), another S_SP...};` map's element is key,value pair, you just need pass a pair<const string,shared_ptr<set<int>>>, it will compile

Comment: many thanks to you. I've already fixed my code as your method.